# Is there a way to migrate confluence wiki to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, migration, confluence

I have been searching for a way to migrate data from confluence wiki to wordpress but couldn't find a solution.

I have an xml file which is exported from confluence. When I tried to import the xml file into wordpress, I had difficulty matching the structure to wordpress categories.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a simple solution here. WordPress is for publishing, and Confluence is much broader. WordPress is flat, Confluence has wiki spaces and inside the spaces hierarchies of pages. Could you tell us more about your existing Confluence? How many spaces, how many pages, how to match them then? Perhaps there could be a way to use the Confluence REST API and an existing WordPress REST API and some scripting language. But be aware, this will be a lot of work. So if you have 200 pages, just copy and paste for 4 hours, that should be sufficient ...

Comment: It's a 700+ pages wiki, so I think copy and paste won't be convenient. Couldn't find a way to match the xml file generated by confluence, will try to export to html and then import them into WordPress.. Thanks for the idea, now reading through the REST APIs documentation

Comment: Although this question is a bit old i give it a try. Confluence is able to export full documentation to HTML. Build your confluence layout template to like your web-page or even similar and export to html and upload it to your web-server. In wordpress just us en external link (or iframe plugin) to the html documentation exported from confluence.